# Why do you lose reputation for answering a question loses reputation?

Tags: discussion

Having answered https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259609/ with what i consider a fine answer, the question was down voted and has been put on hold for being too broad (which i can agree with).

However i also lost 2 rep because the question was down voted. Why does this happen?

To me it makes no sense as many future users will view this question, especially as it is quite broad, and my answer suits them, but i am punished for someone else's mistake and i am encouraged to remove my answer to avoid any other rep loss.

Comment: Your answer was downvoted, that is why you lost 2 reputation, not because the question was closed or downvoted.

Comment: For the record, why do you think you should gain reputation for answering a broad question?

Comment: This doesn't belong to meta in my opinion.

Comment: Remember that the OP most likely isn't aware that you can see vote counts when you get a high enough rep... that seems to be the real issue here (i.e. cause of confusion).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't lose rep because the question was downvoted. You lost rep because your answer was downvoted. Right now there is one upvote (+10 rep) and one downvote (-2 rep) on your answer.